# Want to add search box for each column which will search in respective column

Tags: html, angular7

[image]I Want to add search box for each column which will search in respective column. For that I have written my code as below but its not working.
home.component.html

```
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <th>Commit Date</th>
    <th>Commit Id</th>
    <th >Environment</th>
    <th>Jira Id's</th>
    <th >Upgrade Date</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th><input [(ngModel)]="searchString1" placeholder="Search.." class="advancedSearchTextbox"></th>
    <th><input [(ngModel)]="searchString2" placeholder="Search.." class="advancedSearchTextbox"></th>
    <th><input [(ngModel)]="searchStrin3" placeholder="Search.." class="advancedSearchTextbox"></th>
    <th><input [(ngModel)]="searchStrin4" placeholder="Search.." class="advancedSearchTextbox"></th>
    <th><input [(ngModel)]="searchString5" placeholder="Search.." class="advancedSearchTextbox"></th>
  </tr>
  <tr *ngFor="let data of history | filter :{ commit_date : searchString1, commit_id: searchString2, env: searchString3, jira_ids: searchString4, upgrade_date: searchString5};">
    <td class="text-left">
      {{data.commit_date}}
    </td>
    <td>{{data.commit_id}}</td>
    <td>{{data.env}}</td>
    <td>{{data.jira_ids}}</td>
    <td>{{data.upgrade_date}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

filter.pipe.ts

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
@Pipe({
  name: 'filter'
})
@Injectable()
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(items: any, filter: any, defaultFilter: boolean): any {
    if (!filter){
      return items;
    }
    if (!Array.isArray(items)){
      return items;
    }
    if (filter && Array.isArray(items)) {
      let filterKeys = Object.keys(filter);
      if (defaultFilter) {
        return items.filter(item =>
            filterKeys.reduce((x, keyName) =>
                (x && new RegExp(filter[keyName], 'gi').test(item[keyName])) || filter[keyName] == "", true));
      }
      else {
        return items.filter(item => {
          return filterKeys.some((keyName) => {
            return new RegExp(filter[keyName], 'gi').test(item[keyName]) || filter[keyName] == "";
          });
        });
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It works fine if I add a single search box at top and change HTML file like below:

```
Search Data Here: </b><input [(ngModel)]="searchString" placeholder="Search.." class="advancedSearchTextbox">
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <th>Commit Date</th>
    <th>Commit Id</th>
    <th >Environment</th>
    <th>Jira Id's</th>
    <th >Upgrade Date</th>
  </tr>
  <tr *ngFor="let data of history | filter :{ commit_date : searchString, commit_id: searchString, env: searchString, jira_ids: searchString, upgrade_date: searchString};">
    <td class="text-left">
      {{data.commit_date}}
    </td>
    <td>{{data.commit_id}}</td>
    <td>{{data.env}}</td>
    <td>{{data.jira_ids}}</td>
    <td>{{data.upgrade_date}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

What changes do I need to make the search box work for each individual column

Comment: do you want to do something like filter with searchbox? Also each search clean the prev search or search on search?

Comment: Yes I want to do filter with search-box and each search clean the prev search. but if I put two filters suppose for two different columns it should return intersection of those. I hope you understand what I mean.

Comment: do you must use pipe?

Comment: If there is any other way to do that without using pipes also then its welcomed. I also added an image for reference.

Comment: see my answer please

Comment: Yes Its working awesome, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use one parameter for the search input and use function that get the key and the name of the column as below:

**HTML:**

```
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <th>Commit Date</th>
    <th>Commit Id</th>
    <th >Environment</th>
    <th>Jira Id's</th>
    <th >Upgrade Date</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th><input  placeholder="Search.." class="advancedSearchTextbox" [ngModel]="searchString" (ngModelChange)="search($event,'commit_date')" ></th>
    <th><input placeholder="Search.." class="advancedSearchTextbox" [ngModel]="searchString" (ngModelChange)="search($event,'commit_id')"></th>
    <th><input placeholder="Search.." class="advancedSearchTextbox" [ngModel]="searchString" (ngModelChange)="search($event,'env')"></th>
    <th><input placeholder="Search.." class="advancedSearchTextbox" [ngModel]="searchString" (ngModelChange)="search($event,'jira_ids')"></th>
    <th><input placeholder="Search.." class="advancedSearchTextbox" [ngModel]="searchString" (ngModelChange)="search($event,'upgrade_date')"></th>
  </tr>
  <tr *ngFor="let data of filterData">
    <td class="text-left">
      {{data.commit_date}}
    </td>
    <td>{{data.commit_id}}</td>
    <td>{{data.env}}</td>
    <td>{{data.jira_ids}}</td>
    <td>{{data.upgrade_date}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**TS:**

```
  history = [
    {
      commit_date: "20/02/2019",
      commit_id: "52",
      env: "log",
      jira_ids: "jira",
      upgrade_date: "02/03/2019"
    },
    {
      commit_date: "03/03/2019",
      commit_id: "53",
      env: "log",
      jira_ids: "jira",
      upgrade_date: "03/04/2019"
    }
  ];
  searchString="";
  filterData:any=[];

  constructor(){
    this.filterData = this.history;
  }

  search(term,columnName){
       if(!term) {
      this.filterData = this.history;
    } else {
      this.filterData = this.history.filter(x => 
         x[columnName].trim().toLowerCase().includes(term.trim().toLowerCase())
      );
    }
  }
```